# Loading data from Redshift Query in dataframe (with Spark) is taking way too long. How to tune?

Tags: python, pyspark, dask

I am working in Databricks and running a SQL query from Redshift. Then, I want to load it into a dataframe for manipulation but it takes too long and I wonder if there are other techniques to speed up?

This is how I am loading currently:

```
sql = """ select * from table1 """
df = query_redshift(spark, sql).toPandas()
```

Comment: how much data present at source table?Can you add code snippet so that we can help here..try removing toPandas() function

Comment: @devesh It is about 4 million rows. That is the snippet I have. If I remove .toPandas() how do I create another dataframe?

Comment: maybe try to do most of the operations in spark and bring in a smaller amount of data in pandas.

Comment: @titutubs purpose of asking code snippet is  whether you are using redshift spark connector or jdbc connection.Anyway I guess you're ultimate aim is to get data in pandas DF while I am asking to check with load() function to create pyspark DF first and add simple action on that DF to confirm problem is at processing stage or its at source table itself?
toPandas() function kick off normal python process to convert from pyspark DF to pandas DF one which can be slow depending   on data volume and available resources